# Is it possible for companies to specify which caliber of candidates can view their "Looking for a job?" ads?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs

I've noticed that the positions being shown on the "[Looking for a job?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90hkb.png)" ad are way out of my league. I would personally like to see something which is more realistic for my skill levels.

I'm not there yet, but I'm getting there though. Too slow for my taste, but constraints bound by time and human flesh are unfortunately not in the realm of trivial subjects for now.

So why not let companies offer the choice to further narrow down on the base skill level they would like to see in people applying for their positions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 4):

This is something we're actively working on in an effort to better match a bunch of developer attributes to jobs that we think would be a good fit for them.

It touches both parts of the equation; posting a job will include some additional (optional) fields such as seniority and developers will also be able to provide more information about their tech stack, experience and location preferences which will feed the matching algorithm.

This will largely affect the interesting tab's algorithm on Careers but it's likely that once we have proven various aspects of the algorithm that it will feed the ad-serving mechanisms as well.

Comment: Hey Dean, can you please take a look at [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267944/is-it-possible-for-companies-to-specify-which-caliber-of-candidates-can-view-the/267946?noredirect=1#comment869493_267946)? I don't see such screen, and wonder if what OP is asking about is possible? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will work, since "skill level" can't really be measured.

Someone with zero experience might turn out as a super genius, and complete complex projects, that others with 10 years of experience failed to do. Someone with 10 years of experience, 1000 successful projects, comes to new company and fail in some trivial test/project.

My point is, that companies should specify technical requirements, nothing more.

Comment: Aren't there any variables which combined can form a rough idea of one's skill on the SE network? For example, amount of questions successfully answered, bounties and upvotes received, badges collected over time etc.?

Comment: @AppAraat perhaps, but Careers is not directly tied to Stack Exchange reputation/badges system and should not be. Having rep/badges requirement will not be a good idea.

Comment: I'm curious, do you think users of Careers should have a choice of coupling their Stack profiles and if not, why not?

Comment: What do you mean "coupling their Stack profiles"? How?

Comment: I've noticed you can add your StackOverflow account to it. This way you could also add other networks of SE as well (such as vi/vim and Unix & Linux).

Comment: @AppAraat you mean the big orange button in the profile page? Yes, you can choose to show it on any site when editing your profile. Also, in the Careers profile itself you can add as many SE sites as you want: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4AzrV.png (so those sites are visible in your public resume)

Comment: Oh cool, had no idea you could do that, but I was actually referring to the reverse :p
So basically instead of _only_ having ability to link your SO profile and GH profile [here](http://i.imgur.com/tazqVBh.png), you would also have the choice from all other SE network sites you have a profile on.

Comment: @AppAraat what is this screen? I never saw it. How you got to it?

Comment: I just clicked on "My Profile". The link I was looking at is this - https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/privacy

Perhaps it's something new? I only recently linked my SE OpenID to Careers.

Comment: Still no idea, asked the SE developer to have a look though.

Comment: @AppAraat That screen is normally reached when you don't have a Careers profile. We only show SO and GH there because a) Careers is developer focused and b) those two sites are the most commonly linked by our existing users. Once you create the profile you can add other sites in the SE network by going to the 'Stack Exchange' section. (that's the image Shadow Wizard linked to).